# Command line calculator with multiple input numbers and operators?

Tags: java, calculator

Newbie to Java; I've created a Command line calculator that gets a double from user and gets one operation symbol and gets another double from user and the calculates the amount.

This is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class forthProblem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double numb1, numb2, add, subtract, multiply, divide;
        char operation;


        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Calculate: ");
            numb1 = in.nextDouble();
            operation = in.next().charAt(0);
            numb2 = in.nextDouble();

            switch (operation) {
            case '+':
                add = numb1 + numb2;
                System.out.println(add);
                break;

            case '-':
                subtract = numb1 - numb2;
                System.out.println(subtract);
                break;
            case '*':
                multiply = numb1 * numb2;
                System.out.println(multiply);
                break;
            case '/':
                divide = numb1 / numb2;
                System.out.println(divide);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to figure out is how to be able to get multiple numbers from users and do multiple operations.
for example a user could type (3+4)*4/6= and get an answer.
Also I would like to implement the bedmas in the new code.

I'll appreciate your guidance.

Comment: Mathematical expression evaluation might be too big of a leap if you're a newbie. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/expression-evaluation/

Comment: This is a great opportunity to learn about grammars and parsing. It will take some learning, though...

Answer (score 1):

In order to implement PEMDAS and do multiple operations, you will need to keep all input until the user sends in '='. One way to do this is [reverse polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). Just transform the string to RPN and then run through the equation.